# Is there any profiler able to identify the name of variables being copied in and out GPU with openacc program

Tags: nsight, openacc

I'm trying to accelerate a legacy MPI Fortran program with GPU and OpenACC. And after I compile and profile the program with Nsight system, I found some unexpected data copy from HtoD and DtoH. I want to mitigate those data transfers by copy them in advance, but I could not find out what exactly was copied in and out. The program is quite large with many many source files, is there any ways to quickly identify the variable name corresponding to memcpy HtoD and DtoH shown on the profiler.

I also tried with PGI_ACC_DEBUG mode, but the information is overwhelming and I could not identify which is actually the data transfer I'm looking for. Is there some good practices to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know a way to get this association from Nsight-systems.  You might try using the environment variable "PGI_ACC_NOTIFY=2".  This displays a more concise debug output, showing the file line, variable name, and size in bytes.  Note that PGI_ACC_NOTIFY uses a bit mask to control what's being displayed with "1" being the kernel launches, "2" being the data transfers, and "3" being both.

Comment: Try this first. If it doesn't work, I have a library built on profiling interface that might help, but it's extremely verbose.